# Button to print the the Text Input is not working

Tags: python, kivy

The whole code is working well. But when u go to:

```
student > Add New student > > Fill all columns of new student > then submit
```

it's not working and I can't figure out the issue. Here is the following code. Any help will be appreciated

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen ,FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
import csv
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

Builder.load_string("""
<MenuScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Teacher'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'screen1'
        Button:
            text: 'Student '
            on_press:root.manager.current = 'screen2'
        Button:
            text: 'Quit'

<Screen1>:
    BoxLayout:

    Button:
        text: 'Teacher Info'
        #on_press:root.manager.current = 'login'
    Button:
        text: 'Teacher Attandance'
    Button:
        text: 'Add New Teacher'
        on_press:root.manager.current = 'add_teacher'
    Button:
        text: 'Back'
        on_press:root.manager.current ='menu'


<add_new_teacher>:
    GridLayout:
        cols:2

    Label:
        text:'Name'
    TextInput:
        id: name_input
        multiline: False

    Label:
        text:'Father Name'
    TextInput:
        id: name_input
        multiline: False

    Label:
        text: 'Mother Name'
    TextInput:
        id: name_input
        multiline: False

    Label:
        text: 'Class'
    TextInput:
        id: name_input
        multine: False

    Label:
        text:'Roll no.'
            text: 'Student Info'
            on_press:root.csv_std()
        Button:
            text: 'Student Attandance'
            # on_press:root.manager.current ='login'
        Button:
            text: 'Add New Student'
            on_press:root.manager.current = 'add_student'

        Button
            text: 'Back'
            on_press:root.manager.current = 'menu'

<add_new_student>:
    GridLayout:
        cols:2

        Label:
            text:'Name'
        TextInput:
            id: self.name
            multiline: False

        Label:
            text:'Father Name'
        TextInput:
            id: self.fname
            multiline: False

        Label:
            text: 'Mother Name'
        TextInput:
            id: self.mname
            multiline: False

        Label:
            text: 'Class'
        TextInput:
            id: self.c
            multine: False

        Label:
            text:'Roll no.'
        TextInput:
            id: self.r
            multiline:False


        Button:
            text:'Print'


        Button:
            text:'Submit'
            on_press:root.print_text()

        Button:
            text:'Back'
            on_press:root.manager.current= 'screen2'

""")

# Declare both screens
class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass
class add_new_teacher(Screen):

    pass 
class Screen1(Screen):
    pass
class Screen2(Screen):
    def csv_std(self):
        f = open("a.csv", 'r')
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            print(" ".join(row))
    pass
class add_new_student(Screen):
    def print_text(self):
        for child in reversed(self.children):
            if isinstance(child, TextInput):
                print child.text
    pass


# Create the screen manager
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(add_new_teacher(name='add_teacher'))
sm.add_widget(add_new_student(name='add_student'))
sm.add_widget(Screen1(name='screen1'))
sm.add_widget(Screen2(name='screen2'))

class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2):

You code formatting was horrible, but at least you didn't use backticks. For future cases, copy&paste your whole example you want to show here, then select that example(whole) and press `Ctrl + K`, which will indent all selected lines, so that it'd look ok.

The code works exactly how it supposed to work, because `root.print_text()` targets `add_new_student` class and its `children` - not `GridLayout` which you want to access.

Edit the line with `for` to this: `for child in reversed(self.children[0].children):` and you are good to go. :)

Or more efficient solution would be to get that `Screen` to behave as a layout too, which you can get with inheritting both from `Screen` and some layout, but ensure the layout is *first*:

```
class add_new_student(GridLayout, Screen):
    def print_text(self):
        for child in reversed(self.children):
            if isinstance(child, TextInput):
                print child.text
```

**kv:**

```
<add_new_student>:
    cols:2

    Label:
        text:'Name'
```

Comment: i accepted that before but due to internet issue it was not been selected.... Thanks for the help

Comment: @Sheena Wadhwa Don't worry about that :)

Comment: @EL3PHANTEN a question has "answered" status even when there's no accepted answer. Simple upvote is enough.